# Scroll Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting

i need help my stuff isn't working i'm not sure why. It's a scroll function that moves a navigation bar 20 px down if the window isn't at the top of document. And its supposed to move back 20px once the window is scrolled to the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()- $(window).height() ){
            $('#nav_space').animate({top:'20px'},200);
        }
       else {
                $('#nav_space').animate({top:'-3px'},200);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="nav_space">
    <div id="nav_symbol">

    </div>
    <div id="nav_name">
    <h3>Ascension</h3>
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 19px; top: 39px;">Entertainment</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong? Are you getting an error message? Nothing happens? The wrong thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify using `scrollTop()`.  Change your javascript to this instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > 0){  
            $('#nav_space').animate({top:'20px'},200);
        }
       else {
                $('#nav_space').animate({top:'-3px'},200);
        }
    });
```